# Ubuntu 18.04 headless with Nvidia card - Nvidia persistence

Tags: drivers, server, 18.04, nvidia

I am running long time computations (several hours) on a Nvidia RTX 2080 GPU installed in Ubuntu 18.04 headless (no peripheral connected to the computer: no monitor, no keyboard, etc...).

Do I have to use Nvidia persistence ?

According to this post:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1049821/geforce-2080-rtx-ti-on-ubuntu-18-04-stops-working-after-a-while/

the Nvidia person seems to suggest that Nvidia persistence should be activated.

So, as Nvidia documentation is not clear for me (see https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/driver-persistence/index.html),

1) Is it necessary ?

2) If yes, how do I launch it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch nvidia persistence by running

```
sudo nvidia-persistenced
```

As this runs the persistence daemon with root privileges, you might want to use the `--user` flag. If you want to start it automatically on boot, you can modify the service `/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service` to use `--persistence-mode` instead of `--no-persistence-mode`.

You can check that by using `nvidia-smi`, which should show on the top left corner, that `Persistence-M` is **On**.